# MySQL in XAMPP won't start

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

I restarted my computer while the XAMPP software was running in the background (have done it multiple times before). When I was going to start XAMPP once more, MySQL will not start!

How can I fix this problem without losing any databases? I'm using Windows 10.

```
2017-10-24 16:40:56 2244 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 1835037 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 1835127 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table mysql/gtid_slave_pos in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 10, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 2, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 1, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table mysql/slave_master_info in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 4, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table mysql/slave_relay_log_info in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 3, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table mysql/slave_worker_info in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 5, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__bookmark in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 11, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__central_columns in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 27, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__column_info in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 12, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__designer_settings in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 28, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__export_templates in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 29, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__favorite in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 16, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__history in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 13, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__navigationhiding in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 25, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__pdf_pages in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 14, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__recent in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 15, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__relation in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 18, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__savedsearches in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 26, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__table_coords in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 19, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__table_info in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 20, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__table_uiprefs in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 17, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__tracking in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 21, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 22, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__usergroups in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 24, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma__users in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 23, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-10-24 16:40:56 11080 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"mysql"."innodb_index_stats"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 2.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 2b48  InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 11080 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/innodb_index_stats'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 11080 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"mysql"."innodb_table_stats"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 1.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 2b48  InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 11080 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/innodb_table_stats'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.0 started; log sequence number 1835127
2017-10-24 16:40:56 10092 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-10-24 16:40:56 8772 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Did you have temporary tables? ... Did you try the information provided by the URL in the log? Scroll down to the section: "Tablespace Does Not Exist" on that page.

Comment: No temporary tables what I know about. Didn't try the guidens in the URL because... to be honest, I don't know. Will test it soon :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

16M is much too small for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  How much RAM do you have?  Well, set the buffer_pool to 200M for now (in my.cnf).